# Adapter is not parsing the arraylist which I am sending to it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am using this swipe library https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

Here is the code from where I am getting data and storing in ArrayList (the data is coming from the server correctly)

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(mMessage);
                    JSONArray profiles = json.getJSONArray("profiles");

                    for (int j = 0; j < profiles.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject object =(JSONObject) profiles.get(j);
                       //add a model
                        profiles model =new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(object), profiles.class);
                        profile_list.add(model);
                        profiles_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```

These are the declaration of the adapters and Arraylist

```
    profiles_adapter = new profiles_adapter(this,R.layout.cards,profile_list);
    SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer  = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);
    flingContainer.setAdapter(profiles_adapter);
```

This is my adapter code

```
public class profiles_adapter  extends ArrayAdapter<profiles> {
Context context;


public profiles_adapter(Context context, int resourceId, ArrayList<profiles> item) {
    super(context, resourceId, item);
    this.context=context;
}
  Public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   final profiles profile = getItem(position);


    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cards, parent, false);
    }

    TextView card_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_name);
    card_name.setText(profile.getPet_name());
    TextView card_age = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_age);
    card_age.setText(profile.getAge());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes in your code as below,

```
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(mMessage);
                JSONArray profiles = json.getJSONArray("profiles");

                for (int j = 0; j < profiles.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject object =(JSONObject) profiles.get(j);
                   //add a model
                    profiles model =new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(object), profiles.class);
                    profile_list.add(model);

                }
            profiles_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And the Adapter file would be

```
  public class profiles_adapter  extends ArrayAdapter<profiles> {
 Context context;
 Arraylist<profiles> profileArraylist;

 public profiles_adapter(Context context, int resourceId, ArrayList<profiles> 
 item) {

this.context=context;
this.profileArraylist = item;
 }
Public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final profiles profile = profileArraylist.get(position);


if (convertView == null){
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cards, parent, false);
}

TextView card_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_name);
card_name.setText(profile.getPet_name());
TextView card_age = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_age);
card_age.setText(profile.getAge());
 }
```

Try this out it would help you to finger out the problem.

Comment: No it's not working but debugger is saying : profiles.getView() , Suspended thread

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: should I post xml of card layout and swipe layout ?

Comment: Yes, can you also post logs file which is getting above error